# Value of Planck scale

Tags: quantum-gravity, physical-constants, absolute-units

I read several times that the [Planck scale](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck_energy) is the energy scale at which the effects of gravity are comparable to the effects of the other fundamental forces.

How can I show that this actually happens at $10^{19}$ GeV?

Comment: I found the answer myself: if one asks that the gravitational effect $G M^2/r$ is equal to the rest mass $M c^{2}$ one obtains $M c^{2}=10^{19}$ if the distance r is a natural unit of length. Regards

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer myself: requiring that the gravitational potential $GM^2/r$ is equal to the rest mass $Mc^2$, one obtains for r equal to a natural unit of length $Mc^2=1.22\times10^{19}$ GeV that is the Planck scale.